# K-Fold on a Random Forest

Tags: regression, cross-validation, python, random-forest

I have a 1400x120 matrix that I'm aiming to run a random forest regression on but have been running into difficulty understanding how the RF interacts with K-fold.

Specifically, is cross validation run on the entire data-set (thus negating the need to partition into training/test), or is it only run on the training subset?

I'm unconvinced that this is right, but is K-Fold CV used to determine the optimal tuning parameters, or have I confused that with something else? If not, what is being achieved by running the CV?

Having obtained my data and committed to a random forest regression, I'm looking to understand what further tests I need to do in order to; 1. improve the model to its optimal settings, and 2. sufficiently report the results.

Comment: Welcome to cross validated! It will be up to you to say what you want the cross validation results for. You can use them for verification/validation (reporting) xor for data-driven optimization. Just keep in mind that you can use them only once, i.e. if you use them for optimization, you'll need another, so-called outer cross validation for verification purposes.

Comment: CV lets you "diagnose" overfitting but does not fix it for you. It is used to benchmark the performance of different algorithms (or of different parametrisations and model structures of the same algorithm), in a more efficient way than simply performing a single train-test split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to perform Cross-Validation with a RF model, as the model performs and calculates its own CV metric known as OOB score. The confusion matrix printed by the model is calculated based on these OOB scores.

The function itself doesn't auto-tune the model based on the OOB score, you have to specify what you want to tune.

Usually you would build a number of different models (with different parameters / arguments), choose the one that returns the best metric based on the OOB scores (Error rate, Accuracy, F-score, etc.) and then test the chosen model on a test set.